# Trying to obtain the value of variable passed through text editor?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

```
proc editor {} {
    label .l_LNum -text "Calibration Date"
    entry .e_Num -width 20 -relief sunken -textvariable num

    grid config .l_LNum -column 0 -row 0 -sticky e
    grid config .e_Num -column 1 -row 0 -sticky "snew"
}
```

This is a small example of the proc that I'm talking about here.
How do I check the contents of `$num` because puts doesn't seem to work?

Comment: `num` will be in the global scope, so try `puts $::num`

Comment: that worked, thanks!! can you explain more about it? And can I still do operations based on that value?

Comment: There's a section in the tutorial about scopes: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl13.html -- Also, the Tk `options` man page where `-textvariable` is documented: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/options.htm#M-textvariable

Comment: And yes, you can use that variable however you like.

Answer (score 0):

Variables referred to by Tk widgets are always global (or in another namespace, if you use a qualified name) since the widgets can persist after a procedure has returned and Tcl does not make closures. It would be a seismic change if that was altered, and I don't think it is very likely as it would make debugging a script significantly more difficult. (Also, it'd need a different way of doing memory management, and that's the sort of thing that is horrid to write and get correct and would have a lot of knock-on effects too.)

Because Tk uses the variable name in a global context, to access the variable from within a procedure you need to either use a qualified name or bring it into scope. For example:

```
proc get_the_number {} {
    return $::num
}
```

```
proc get_the_number {} {
    global num
    return $num
}
```

If your procedure is going to refer to the variable multiple times in your procedure, it is typically faster to use `global` instead of the qualified form, but the difference is small enough that “write what is clearest for you” is our official advice.